# Insert / Update / Delete and Fetch JSON in MySql using Laravel

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, laravel

Please correct me if I'm doing it wrong.

I have a JSON encoded array inserted in my database

Upon inserting it It looks like this

["Time Ultra,5.00,5","Downy Antibac,7.00,3","Zonrox Bleach,12.00,1"]

Same with fetch if I do not decode it, then it will display as is.

Now I want to update let say for example I want to update or delete the MIddle part which is

"Downy Antibac,7.00,3"

How do I update or delete it.

Here's my code so far on the insert part

```
$activities = Activities::find($request->input('activityid'));

        $itemList = Activities::where('id', $request->input('activityid'))->pluck('item_list')->first();

        $itemA = json_decode($itemList);
    

        if (!$itemA) {
            $itemB[] = $request->input('item_name').','.$request->input('item_price').','.$request->input('item_qty');
            $activities->service_list = json_encode($itemB);
        }else{
            $itemB = $request->input('item_name').','.$request->input('item_price').','.$request->input('item_qty');
            array_push($itemA,$itemB);
            $activities->service_list = json_encode($itemA);

        }

        $activities->update();
```

Please advice if I'm doing something wrong or not to be done in programming.

I did this coz my table looks like this

[image]

Comment: are you in control of this JSON structure?

Comment: Don't use JSON. Create a table that has `product, price, quantity` (or whatever those three values are) columns instead and JOIN to that. You will thank yourself in the future.

Comment: @lagbox Yes. I control those.

Comment: @Nick i updated the original post and added the table structure

Comment: Specify your MySQL version precisely. *How do I update or delete it.* What is a criteria? Anycase you must parse your array to separate elements, update or delete the element (find it previously by some criteria for this operation), then reconstruct the array back with new element state (or without it).

Comment: wouldn't it be easier if they were grouped as arrays or some structure instead of as a single string for each element?  `[["Time Ultra","5.00",5],["Downy Antibac","7.00",3],["Zonrox Bleach","12.00",1]]`  then you can more easily search for things and replace elements?

Answer (score 0):

To handle JSON-type fields in MySQL, Laravel's Eloquent ORM supports type casting in `JSON` and also custom casting extendability. Read this link; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting